# Azure CDN geo redirect

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have files in blob storage that I'd like to host.  I would like end users to go to a certain path and then receive a response that is specific to their country.

Eg I have files:
usa.js
uk.js

I'd like users go to xxxx.edgesites.net and then receive their usa.js if they are in US and uk.js if they are in UK.

The geo filtering feature of azure CDN looks like it only allows or blocks access according to geo location.

Is there another way of getting to my end goal?  Maybe CDN -> Function -> blob ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually do this all in Azure CDN in the Verizon Premium profile.

The Premium profile offers the Rules Engine - Location match condition, which you can use with a URL Rewrite feature to direct to locale specific files.

See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine-reference-match-conditions#Location

Comment: Thanks!  Could you help me with what I should actually be putting in the rules engine?  It's painfully slow to wait for new rules to be active and I seem to be putting in all the wrong values.  I was thinking:  if ( country matches "US")  then URL rewrite source:"(.*)"  to "us-$1".   Then all requests going into the CDN would fetch a 'us-' version of the file instead.

Comment: Is this for just 1 js file, or a large number?

Comment: Just a couple files.

Comment: What is odd is that I got it working with a weird config.  I have to setup two rules.  One for /xxxxx/ and another for /xxxxx/CDNendpoint/.    The rules are the same for both otherwise:   if ( country matches "US")  then URL rewrite source:"world/(.*)"  to "us/$1".   Any idea why it works like this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure CDN wont work for you with this since it caches a single file for global distribution in a manner that saves Internet latency to speed up downloads.

To implement what you're looking for, you can use Azure Traffic Manager. Create Traffic Manager using the Performance algorithm. Then specify an External Endpoint that points to your Azure Storage Account, and place an Azure Storage Account in a US region, and a Storage Account in UK region. However, you'll need to name the files with the same filename. Then when user in each region attempt to download the file, they will get directed to the Azure Region closest to them in terms of Internet latency.

The requests will work like this once you have Traffic Manager and your Storage Accounts setup correctly:

```
USA User -> hits domain.com -> directed to US region -> downloads file.js for US

UK User -> hits domain.com -> directed to UK region -> downloads file.js for UK
```

Alternatively you could also use the Geographic routing algorithm with Traffic Manager to direct users in specific countries to specific endpoints. This may actually work better for you in the scenario you described.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods

Comment: thanks, the downside to this is I need to setup a domain.

Comment: @Quincy You could just use the Azure CDN subdomain as your endpoint, with out setting up a custom domain.

Comment: thanks, sounds like on the Azure CDN I make an endpoint with 'custom origin'  and I put in the traffic manager address into that?

Comment: @Quincy The way I've described would use Traffic Manager only; no CDN.

Comment: I don't have a domain though.  Not sure if Traffic Manager is useable without a domain?  There's a lot of red tape involved in creating something like thisIsMyDomain.com

Comment: I tried making a new endpoint , 'external endpoint' with FQDN of a blob.  Azure complains saying it's an invalid domain.